# Python intra-package imports and unit tests

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I've searched for a solution here and on other sites, but it feels like all import problems I come across are subtly different.

I have a project with the following setup:

- /

  - __init__.py
  - package1

    - ___init__.py
    - a.py
    - b.py
    - tests/

      - test_a.py
      - test_a.py
  - package2
  - package3

In b.py:

`from .a import Foo`

In the tests:
`import a, b`

package1, package2, and package3 are essentially smaller packages that are bundled together in the same project/super-package as utilities. The purpose of this project is to be nested inside another package (say, package4) and to have these packages/modules imported by package4. Hence, relative imports to other files in the package are required, if I don't want to modify the path.

As an example, package4:

- /

  - main.py
  - src/

    - external/

      - project_from_above

        - package1
        - package2
        - package3

I'm omitting the __init__.py's in the hierarchy above. In main.py, I might do:

`import src.external.project_from_above.package1.a`

**My problem**: this structure works fine, except for unit testing. I am in the habit of running `python3 -m unittest discover tests` from each package (package1, package2, package3). This works fine when there are not relative imports. However, running with relative imports will yield the following error: "SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import"

**I desire**:
A way of running the unit tests in package1/tests from the package1 directory, with no imports changing (or at least, maintaining the ability to use this entire project inside the aforementioned package4 as a sub-package). I'd like to avoid any manipulation of the path, but if we can restrict it to a run_tests.py file in package1, then that is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution: add a file called run_tests in package1. In it, do the following:

```
cd ..
python -m unittest discover package1/tests
```

This requires you to use absolute imports in your tests (e.g., `import package1.a`)